# Why isn't command line not finding finding my .java files?

Tags: java

I am using Windows CMD, and for some reason, I am getting this error message relating to my .java files. For example, I am typing:

```
javac FirstProgram.java
```

However, this error message occurs:

```
javac: file not found: FirstProgram.java   
Usage: javac <options> <source files> 
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I typed in `javac -version`, and I am currently using javac 1.8.0_144. Someone on in another Stack Overflow question suggested to change the System Variables. I used `JAVA_HOME` as the variable name, and I copied the path to my JDK folder, but thus far, I haven't had much luck. I still receive the same error message.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running the command from the wrong folder.

Comment: The most proable explanation is that there is no file FirstProgram.java. What is the output of `dir`?

Comment: show us directory tree

Comment: Please update your post with this additional information: 1) Copy/paste the contents of "FirstProgram.java". 2) From the same command prompt you're using for "javac", type `dir *.java`, and copy/paste that, too.

Comment: Probably you are in the wrong directory. I'm not a windows fan but you can check that the file exists using the `dir` command.

Comment: Well, I know that this particular java file is in Documents in my directory. I am trying to copy the entire directory tree, however, in Notepad++, for example, I am not even allowed to save my FirstProgram.java in the Java folder in Documents. I am forced to save that program in another folder, My Documents. I don't have access to save any of my files to Notepad++.

Comment: I wish there was a program out there where the text editor and the compiler are included. Windows cmd is making compiling so much more complicated.

Comment: 1) Yes there are programs out there.  They are called IDEs.  2) But I recommend that you persist with a simple text editor and the command line ... *because every programmer needs to understand how they work*.  3) Maybe what you need to do is to find a tutorial on the Windows command prompt that explains (among other things) the *current directory*, how to create a directory and how to change directory.  Also, how environment variables and the command search path works.

Comment: Stephan C, that would be most helpful. Thank you.

Comment: In command prompt, change the directory to directory where , your java file resides

Answer (score 1):

Run the dir or dir/p command to see your directory contents on your command prompt

> c:\path\to\your program directory\dir

See if FirstProgram.java is listed or not? If not then you are in a wrong directory.

Now you have two options

1. You change to the correct directory using cd command or
2. You use the absolute path for your FirstProgram.java file

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use absolute path while using the command if it says the file isn't found.

```
javac /some/directory/path/to/the/file/FirstProgram.java
```

***Note***: On command line, most of the shells would anyway not let you complete the path if the file doesn't exist there. And the other way if you're copying the path from an explorer/finder, it shall be guaranteed to be existing.

***Edit***: The absolute path as pointed out in comments would be using forward slashes in Windows, e.g :

```
javac \some\directory\path\to\the\file\FirstProgram.java
```

Comment: When I did that, I got the error message about a false flag.

Comment: @Robert absolute path are still available in windows. what's wrong in there?

Comment: @nullpointer - The problem is that a forward slash is an option on Windows.

Comment: @Bijou - The absolute pathname for a file on a Windows command line will look something like `C:\some\path\FirstProgram.java`.  Can I suggest that you re-read my comment above ......

Comment: @StephenC Correct. I primarily meant the absolute path, the slashes used were just to denote path format. Would still update the answer.

Comment: @nullpointer - Clearly, the OP is having problems with the basics of Windows and the Windows command prompt.  There is only so much we can do .....

Comment: Paths containing spaces must be enclosed by double quote `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to that specific folder containing that program then [ Shift + L_Click ], click open cmd, then run it again to ensure it is being ran in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here ... including why

PROBLEM 1:

> "...I am not even allowed to save my FirstProgram.java in the Java
>   folder in Documents."  <= ?!?

PROBLEM 2:

> "...I got the error message about a false flag"  <= This is probably a space "  " in the path name

STRONG SUGGESTION:

Download Eclipse and try compiling and running your program from Eclipse.  In other words, using an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)), instead of the command line.

You can download Eclipse here:

- http://eclipse.org

There is a good "starters tutorial" here:

- [Creating your first Java project](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-3.htm)

Answer (score -1):

This is my a simplified *DOSJavaIDE environment* for simple test applications if Eclipse is too much of a hassle. I can point compiling and running an application to a specific JVM version. Study this script to see how folder structure and paths are given in each of the commands.

**Folders and files**

```
c:\projects\test1\classes\
c:\projects\test1\lib\
c:\projects\test1\lib\somelib1.jar
c:\projects\test1\lib\somelib2.jar
c:\projects\test1\src\
c:\projects\test1\src\test\GameLoop2.java
c:\projects\test1\src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
c:\projects\test1\javaenv.bat
```

**javaenv.bat**

```
@REM Standalone JavaDosEnvironment
@set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112

@"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -version

@set cmd=%1
@if "%cmd%"=="" (
  @echo Please specify command to run ^(1..n or empty to exit^)
  @echo 1=Compile, 2=Jar, 12=CompileJar
  @echo 3=Run-test1 GameLoop2 with vsync
  @SET /p cmd="1..n: "
)

@IF /I "%cmd%"=="1"            set cmd=compile
@IF /I "%cmd%"=="compile"      call :COMPILE
@IF /I "%cmd%"=="2"            set cmd=jar
@IF /I "%cmd%"=="jar"          call :JAR
@IF /I "%cmd%"=="12"           set cmd=compilejar
@IF /I "%cmd%"=="compilejar"   (
  call :COMPILE
  call :JAR
)

@IF /I "%cmd%"=="3"            set cmd=run-test1
@IF /I "%cmd%"=="run-test1"    call :RUN-test1
@goto :END


:COMPILE
xcopy /Y .\src\META-INF\*.* .\classes\META-INF\
set cp=./lib/somelib1.jar;./lib/somelib2.jar
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac" -classpath "%cp%" -sourcepath ./src -d ./classes ./src/test/*.java
@goto :eof

:JAR
xcopy /Y .\src\META-INF\*.* .\classes\META-INF\
SET MF=./classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\jar" cvfm ./lib/test.jar %MF% -C ./classes .
@goto :eof

:RUN-test1
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "./lib/*" test.GameLoop2 "fullscreen=false" fps=60 vsync=true
@goto :eof

:END
@pause
```

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Implementation-Title: testapp
Implementation-Version: 1.0.0 (2017-07-21)
Implementation-Vendor: myname
Implementation-URL: http://my.homepage.com/
```

Run this script in a command-line such as `javaenv.bat compile`, `javaenv.bat jar`, `javaenv.bat run-test1` or run without arguments to prompt for selection list.

See a customized manifest where you may write anything you want and is included in a `./lib/test.jar` file. Compile target has few 3rd party dependency libraries in a classpath.